# How to resize matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm unable to resize the graph in my matplotlib scatter plot. I have included `plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))` but it doesn't affect the size.

[Here is the current plot output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io1Po.png)

```
plt.scatter(x['so2_x'],x['state'],alpha=0.5,c=x['so2_x'],s=x['so2_x'])
plt.title("so2@2011 vs state")
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.show
```

Answer (score 25):

This line isn't doing what you think it is.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
```

Instead of adjusting the size of the existing plot, it's creating a new figure with a size of 20x20. Simply move the above line before the call to scatter and things will work as you want.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.scatter(x['so2_x'],x['state'],alpha=0.5,c=x['so2_x'],s=x['so2_x'])
plt.title("so2@2011 vs state")    
plt.show()
```

Another alternative is to change the size after the call to scatter implicitly creates the figure object using gcf() to return the current figure handle.

```
plt.scatter(x['so2_x'],x['state'],alpha=0.5,c=x['so2_x'],s=x['so2_x'])
plt.title("so2@2011 vs state")
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((20, 20))    
plt.show()
```